# Question about Symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

Ok my book says this matrix $A = \left ( \array{ -2 & 1 \\
                    1 & -3 }
    \right )$is symmetric. But, I don't understand b/c if it were a symmetric matrix, wouldn't it be like this $A = \left ( \array{ -2 & 1 \\
                    1 & -2 }
    \right )$? I am confused.

**Question:** If a matrix is symmetric, does that mean it is also a positive definite matrix?

Comment: The definition of a symmetric matrix is a square matrix equal to its transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$ means by definition $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ for all indices $i,j$. This means that entries that are opposite of each other with respect to the **main diagonal** (top left down to bottom right) must be the same. But entries which are opposite of each other with respect to the top right to bottom left diagonal don't have to be the same.

Hope this helps.